# Problems after exporting Tableau Crosstab to Excel

Tags: excel, tableau-api, crosstab, vba

Whenever I export Crosstab to Excell from Tableau, it works fine. But once it's done, I can't use any macros from my personal workbook or move the sheet to another workbook until I save, close, and reopen the new file. Is there some setting I can change to allow faster editing?

Comment: What happens when you Copy the cross tab and paste it into an opened excel workbook?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are downloading a csv file not an excel file. So you are probably saving to excel format after opening and closing the crosstab.

Take a look at the properties of the file after you download (before you open it) then after you open and close the file.